# Compare if BGR image is exactly the same

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to write code to find out if two images are the same. I was able to read the images in as `BGR` and was able to subtract one from another. I need to do a check and see if the difference contains only zeros. I know there is a function called `countNonZero`, but it only works on single channel, not 3 channels. An solution I had was looping through the entire matrix and checking if everything is zero, but that is too slow. Is there any efficient way of checking? Here is my code below.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  if(argc != 3)
  {
    printf("usage: DisplayImage.out <testImg.png> <copy.png>\n");
    return -1; 
  }

  Mat image;
  Mat copy;
  Mat output;

  image = imread(argv[1], 1); 
  copy = imread(argv[2], 1); 

  absdiff(image, copy, output);

  if(countNonZero(output) == 0)
  {
    cout << "Same" << endl;
  }
  else
  {
    cout << "Different" << endl;
  }

  imshow("outut", output);
  waitKey();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I were doing this, I would read the files, then start comparing each CPU-sized word of the data in a for loop.  As soon as a difference is found, exit.  If you get to the end, pass.  This will be faster than storing an array of differences to RAM and comparing after the fact.  I even bet a loop like this would vectorize well.  Whether or not to read the whole files into memory depends on how big they are I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Mat diff_im = image - copy;
double s = cv::sum(diff_im)[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `norm()` function of the OpenCV with the norm type `NORM_L2`

```
double rst = cv::norm(img1, img2, cv::NORM_L2);
```

The result will be zero in case the images are completely the same.

The more similar, the closer to zero.